# objective-c: read an array create by json

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I begin in Ios dev and I got some troubles to manipulate an array create by Json :
I call in my app a web Service which return me data :

```
{evenements =(
             ({
            dateEvenement ={
                1 = "01-01-2013";
                2 = "02-01-2013";
                3 = "03-01-2013";
                4 = "04-01-2013";
            };
            idEvenement = 61;
            nbrInvite = 1;
            nomEvenement = "My event Name";
            nomUtilisateur = "Lucas ";
        }
    ),
 );
}
```

I'm able to get all the values by the following code except for "dateEvenement" :

```
NSArray *msgList;
msgList = [ jsonResults objectForKey:@"evenements" ];

for (NSDictionary *evenements in msgList) {

    for (NSDictionary *evenement in evenements ) {

        NSString *idEvenement = [evenement objectForKey:@"idEvenement"];
        NSString *nomUtilisateur = [evenement objectForKey:@"nomUtilisateur"];
        NSString *nomEvenement = [evenement objectForKey:@"nomEvenement"];
        NSString *nbrInvite = [evenement objectForKey:@"nbrInvite"];

        NSArray *dates = [ evenement objectForKey:@"dateEvenement" ];
     }
}
```

Can you help me for getting datas of "dateEvenement"

Comment: What do you mean by 'I can't get the data'? Also, this has **absolutely nothing to do with Xcode whatsoever.**

Comment: the title is wrong IMHO, you arent trying to manipulate data, you are only reading it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your JSON the `dateEvenement` isn't an Array but a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dates = [ evenement objectForKey:@"dateEvenement"];

for(NSNumber *key in dates) {
   NSString *dateString = [dates objectForKey:key];
   NSLog(%@ : %@, key, dateString); 
}
```

As declared in your JSON example the key's for the dictionary are numbers, thus you should `NSNumber` object for the key type.